# How to hide / show multiple elements with HTML, CSS and Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to create a section similar to apples mac mini section (image below)
Essentially 4 buttons that hide / reveal text beneath.

https://www.apple.com/mac-mini/

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/OomgP.png)

Currently with the code below, when you click again on the same button it disappears, I don't want this to happen. I'm new to javascript so not sure how to eliminate this / if possible.

Thanks

```
  <button class="icon1">Button 1</button>
  <button class="icon2">Button 2</button>
<button class="icon3">Button 3</button>
  <button class="icon4">Button 4</button>
  
  <p class="info info1">Toggle 1</p>
  <p class="info info2">Toggle 2</p>
  <p class="info info3">Toggle 3</p>
  <p class="info info4">Toggle 4</p>
</div>
```

```
 .info2, .info3, .info4 {
  grid-area: scrn;
  display: none;
}

/* decorative only */
body {
  font-size: 4vmin;
  text-align: center;
}
button {
  font-size: 2.5vmin;
}
```

```
$(function() {
    // select the button to click, this can be any element not just a button
    $('.icon1').click(function() {
        // select which info panel to show/hide.
        $('.info1').toggle();
        // hide any info panels that are not info1.
        $('.info').not('.info1').hide();
    });                        
});
$(function() {
    $('.icon2').click(function() {
        $('.info2').toggle();
        $('.info').not('.info2').hide();
    });                        
});
$(function() {
    $('.icon3').click(function() {
        $('.info3').toggle();
        $('.info').not('.info3').hide();
    });                        
});
$(function() {
    $('.icon4').click(function() {
        $('.info4').toggle();
        $('.info').not('.info4').hide();
    });                        
});
```

Comment: Hi and Welcome to SO. Please take the [tour] first and then read [ask]. After that edit your question accordingly and provide the debugging details of your attempt in form of a [repro]. Note, that SO is not a code-writing service where developers will solve an entire project for you. A faithful attempt as well as a research effort is expected.

Comment: Hi Tyler, search Codepen for *[tabmenu](https://codepen.io/search/pens?q=tabmenu)*.

Comment: Check this out : http://jsfiddle.net/iamacatperson/R85tE/

Answer (score 1):

You probably want something like this for each button:

```
$(function() {
    // select the button to click, this can be any element not just a button
    $('.icon1').click(function() {
        // hide all info panels.
        $('.info').hide();
        // show info panel which belongs to the button.
        $('.info1').show();
    });                        
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `toggle()`, use `show()` instead. toggle means it will show or hide the element. If it's currently being shown and you call `toggle()` it will be hidden and the other way around if it's hidden.

```js
$('.icon1').click(function() {
  // always show
  $('.info1').show();
  // hide any info panels that are not info1.
  $('.info').not('.info1').hide();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   $(function () {
    // select the button to click, this can be any element 
    not just a button
    $(".icon1").click(function () {
      $(".info1").css("display", "none")
        ? // select which info panel to show/hide.
          $(".info1").toggle()
        : null;
      // hide any info panels that are not info1.
      $(".info").not(".info1").hide();
    });
  });
  $(function () {
    $(".icon2").click(function () {
      $(".info2").css("display", "none")
        ? // select which info panel to show/hide.
          $(".info2").toggle()
        : null;
      $(".info").not(".info2").hide();
    });
  });
  $(function () {
    $(".icon3").click(function () {
      $(".info3").css("display", "none")
        ? // select which info panel to show/hide.
          $(".info3").toggle()
        : null;
      $(".info").not(".info3").hide();
    });
  });
  $(function () {
    $(".icon4").click(function () {
      $(".info4").css("display", "none")
        ? // select which info panel to show/hide.
          $(".info4").toggle()
        : null;
      $(".info").not(".info4").hide();
    });
  });
```

With a condition it work in the way i understood u need, but u can find other way with jquery to animate or maybe you can use a library like mo.js or gsap...
https://api.jquery.com/toggle/ (

> The second version of the method accepts a Boolean parameter. If this parameter is true, then the matched elements are shown; if false, the elements are hidden. In essence, the statement:

```
$( "#foo" ).toggle( display );
```

is equivalent to:

```
if ( display === true ) {
  $( "#foo" ).show();
} else if ( display === false ) {
  $( "#foo" ).hide();
```

}
)
This is the way toggle is meant to be used

Answer (score 0):

By your description, you seem to be trying to create an accordion... Which basically is some title that is shown and the content is hidden.

There is a pretty clear example listed [w3schools website](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_accordion.asp).

There is also an option, if you are targetting HTML 5 capable browsers only without javascript that is illustrated[here](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/accordion-using-html-5#:%7E:text=To%20use%20HTML%205%20Accordion,accordion%20into%20our%20HTML%20page.&text=And%20to%20display%20the%20label,a%20caption%20or%20a%20description.)

Hope this helps you... Best regards!